# ASP.NET Core hosted service ExecuteAsync() method doesn't complete

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

Can anyone help me understand why "WHY DOES THIS NEVER GET CALLED?" never gets logged to the console when the application is shutdown in the following code example?

```cs
public class TestBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Executing test background service...");

        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken);

        System.Console.WriteLine("WHY DOES THIS NEVER GET CALLED?");
    }
}
```

This is registered as a hosted service in the `Startup` class, as usual:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHostedService<TestBackgroundService>();
}
```

My expectation was that when the application starts shutting down, the `stoppingToken` is triggered and the call to `Task.Delay()` should return, then the rest of the `ExecuteAsync()` method would execute during the default five second shutdown timeout, before the application forcefully shuts down.

The console shows "Executing test background service..." as expected, but not "WHY DOES THIS NEVER GET CALLED?".

For reference, the base BackgroundService class can be seen and read about here, with an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#implementing-ihostedservice-with-a-custom-hosted-service-class-deriving-from-the-backgroundservice-base-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding in the `stoppingToken`. This token is stopping the `Task.Delay(...)` but with an `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException`
So your call to the log will never be reached.

```cs
// Simplified example
public static async Task Main()
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    // Throws after 2 seconds:
    await Task.Delay(4000, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    // Never reached:
    Console.WriteLine("WHY DOES THIS NEVER GET CALLED?");
}

//Unhandled exception. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
//   at Program.Main()
//   at Program.<Main>()
```

[Full working example can be found here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SvrHvO)

[Task.Delay Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_TimeSpan_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Comment: Ahh you're right. I didn't realise the async method I was awaiting (Task.Delay in this simplified example) threw an exception when the cancellation token was cancelled, I thought it just returned for some reason. Makes sense though now that I think about it, otherwise the rest of the method would execute thinking the call had returned successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As per the MS Documentation available about '[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)'

It is the '[StopAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#stopasync-1)' method that gets invoked when an application begins shutting down and for you to be able to execute something at the time of the application shutting down, you need to implement an override of the StopAsync in the background service class.

So you need to add a method under the ExecuteAsync() in the same class that is something like this-

```
public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("WHY DOES THIS NEVER GET CALLED?");
    await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
}
```

Comment: Sure, but as you can see here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#implementing-ihostedservice-with-a-custom-hosted-service-class-deriving-from-the-backgroundservice-base-class), the StopAsync method in the base class cancels the stoppingToken then awaits the ExecuteAsync() method, so I'd expect it to finish. I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't.